# How to handle Auto suggestion in selenium?

Tags: selenium

/*I want to select Mumbai as source and Delhi as destination from autosuggestion on cleartrip website. I have written below code. Here source is getting handled properly but on destination, autosuggestion list is displayed but nothing get selected from the list. Could someone please help me out*/

```
String baseurl = "https://www.cleartrip.com/";
driver.get(baseurl);
String title = driver.getTitle();
System.out.println(title);
WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
WebElement flighttab = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Flights"));
flighttab.click();
Thread.sleep(5000);
WebElement roundtrip_radio_button = driver.findElement(By.id("RoundTrip"));
roundtrip_radio_button.click();
WebElement from = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='FromTag']"));
WebElement to =driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ToTag']"));
from.clear();
from.sendKeys("Mumbai");
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//ul/li[@class='list']")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul/li[@class='list']")).click();
to.clear();
to.sendKeys("Delhi");
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//ul/li[@class='list']")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul/li[@class='list']")).click();
```

Comment: Try to write the city letters and hit "Tab" (to.send_keys(Keys.TAB))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The xpath that you are using is incorrect. I am providing you the correct xpath and an alternate way to click on the auto-completer (by using className), you can use either of them, both will work fine.  And as the `wait.until` method returns the element, you can directly perform the `click` on it, which would result in one atleast less operation/scraping on the page.

**Autocompleter Correct Xpath:**

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[@class='uiSelected']"))).click();
```

**Autocompleter by className:**

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("uiSelected"))).click();
```

Comment: `.until()` returns the waited for element so you can turn those two lines into one by adding the `.click()` to the end, `wait.until(...).click(); `. With your method you are actually scraping the page (at least) twice, once for the wait and another with the find and click.

Comment: @JeffC yup correct, thanks for mentioning it !! I have updated my answer.